# Why Some Texts Showing in Web Page Cannot be Found in HTML Source?

Tags: html, google-chrome

Here is a excerpt of the HTML source of the webpage. It is a personal resume. (The Html is obtained by viewing source code in Chrome browser). When I view the webpage, it contains quite a lot of texts under the "work experience" part, but when I view the source HTML, those texts are no where to be found!

I tried saving the webpage by Chrome. One option - saving only Html, ended up losing those texts. But by selecting another option - saving all files together with the Html page, the "work experience" content appears. So I guess this part of text must be referenced from one of the source files. Weird thing is, now it is found in the saved Html file. (Whereas it did not exist in the Html file if the "save only html" option was selected!)

I really wanna know how Chrome "save as" works, as I'm planning to develop some cefsharp based application, needing to save complete webpage texts. Before doing that, apparently, I need to know how this Html stuff works by referencing those "hidden" texts.

```
......
<td>Current employer: Gefco International Logistics </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
<!--Work Experience-->
<div class="resume-work" id="workexp_anchor" >
</div>
<!--/Work Experience-->
<!--Project Experience-->
<!--/ Project Experience -->
<!-- Education -->
<div class="resume-education">
<h2><i class="icons32 icons32-education"></i>Educational</h2>
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td colspan="3">
<strong>New York University</strong>（2002/10 - 2005/10）
......
```

Comment: Can you provide source code in jsfiddle

Comment: Hi, ram, these are personal resumes with private information. I cannot post all codes there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the text is showed when the entire files are saved, it sure points to a js file updating the DOM.
This can be done by simply adding: *jQuery*
`$('#someID').html('I would interfare the DOM');`
This can be in the same html file or in your case, a linked .js file.

Comment: Yes, I found the $("#workexp_anchor") in one of the download js files. Now it looks like Chome "save html only" works by simply saving the origial html codes, while "save all files" works by saving the updated DOM.

Comment: But doing so *might* be bad for SEO, as web crawlers do their job before javascript is processed.

Comment: Since this is a large resume pool. I don't think they want individual resumes to be crawled by search engines. Doing so makes sense for such a site. However, it is a real PITA for my work when I try ti save those resumes.